# Latest Jetbrains Rider IDE does not support hot reload for NET Azure Functions

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-functions, hot-reload, jetbrains-rider

I have decided to try out the Rider IDE from Jetbrains. I mainly dev in NET/C# for Azure Functions projects. However, I now realise that it does not support Hot Reload for this scenario, although this is not singled-out in the limitations section of [Rider's documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Hot_Reload.html).

[Here's a repro](https://github.com/mdddev/AzFuncRiderHotReloadRepro) as proof.

Usually, I use VS code for my work, where hot reload also doesn't work. For a *personal* side-project I have tried the Visual Studio Community edition (free) and I am blown away on how much a working hot reload functionality makes a difference on productivity.

I'm a LOB user and do dev on the side and cannot justify for my boss to pay the VS license. Also due to size of the company, I cannot use the community edition.

Therefore I was really hoping, that Rider was able to support hot reload for Azure Functions since it is advertised as a alternative to Visual Studio and a real IDE (compared to VS code). Unfortunately, this is not the case.

Are there some Rider users out there, that got hot reload working with some extra configuration maybe?

Answer (score 0):

> Therefore I was really hoping, that Rider was able to support hot reload for Azure Functions

[image]

- Here you can see the JetBrains is actively tracking the issue related to enabling hot reload support for Azure Functions in Rider under the issue number [RIDER-97027](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-97027). As it indicates that JetBrains is aware of the limitation and is actively considering implementing a solution.

Microsoft has made significant improvements in hot reload capabilities for .NET 5 and later versions, including Azure Functions. You should ensure that you are using a compatible version of the Azure Functions runtime and Visual Studio for the best hot reload experience.

- Thanks, @Khalid Abuhakmeh for the blog post, JetBrains has introduced hot reload support for .NET 6 in Rider 2021.3. please check this [link](https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2021/10/25/hot-reload-for-net-6-in-rider-2021-3/).

[image]

[image]